# Java & MySql - How to escape query before execute it

Tags: java, mysql, sql-injection

I'm using Java for a web application, and I'm working with a MySql database. I need to escape the query before execute it. This is my actual code :

```
db_result=mydb.selectQuery("SELECT nickname FROM users WHERE nickname='"+log_check_user+"' AND password='"+log_check_pass+"'");

public Vector selectQuery(String query) {
  Vector v = null;
  String [] record;
  int colonne = 0;
  try {
     Statement stmt = db.createStatement();
     ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
     v = new Vector();
     ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
     colonne = rsmd.getColumnCount();

     while(rs.next()) {
        record = new String[colonne];
        for (int i=0; i<colonne; i++) record[i] = rs.getString(i+1);
        v.add( (String[]) record.clone() );
     }
     rs.close();
     stmt.close();
  } catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); errore = e.getMessage(); }

  return v;
 }
```

I need this, as you can believe, to avoid the SQL Injection problem! How can I do it?

Comment: What’s db? What kind of object; which class? Depending on the DB driver you use, there may be better ways, like using prepared statements.

Comment: MySql...i've written it :) jdbc driver!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use a [prepared statement](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html):

> Sometimes it is more convenient to use a `PreparedStatement` object for sending SQL statements to the database. This special type of statement is derived from the more general class, `Statement`...
>
> If you want to execute a `Statement` object many times, it usually reduces execution time to use a `PreparedStatement` object instead.
>
> The main feature of a `PreparedStatement` object is that, unlike a `Statement` object, it is given a SQL statement when it is created. The advantage to this is that in most cases, this SQL statement is sent to the DBMS right away, where it is compiled. As a result, the `PreparedStatement` object contains not just a SQL statement, but a SQL statement that has been precompiled. This means that when the `PreparedStatement` is executed, the DBMS can just run the `PreparedStatement` SQL statement without having to compile it first...

Comment: +1. Also, Vector is considered to be deprecated, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1386275/why-java-vector-class-is-considered-obsolete-or-deprecated

Comment: In all discussions of SQL injection, this link is compulsory: http://xkcd.com/327/